# Is it possible to call TextField in dart file in my Java code on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter

I have integrated Flutter module on my existing Android Project. I have created a page in dart, I want to replace the Native XML Files of my existing Android Project to Dart, after that my new dart file has a TextView and i want to use the user's text input which is the phone number in my java code. How do I do that?

This is my Java code that is currently using the XML File to get the phone number

```
mPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberSignIn);
```

this is my dart file that contains the phone number i want to use

```
 Widget _buildPhoneTF() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Phone Number',
          style: kLabelStyle,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
          height: 60.0,
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.phone_android,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter your phone number',
              hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```